# How to connect ms exchange contatcs to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: exchange-server, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IMporting all Contacts from OUtlook Public Folder into Sharepoint list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37912/importing-all-contacts-from-outlook-public-folder-into-sharepoint-list)

I would like to publish the contacts present in MS Exchange to a SharePoint's Contact List.
Is it possible?